# SFINAE fails for custom template. Need to understand why

Tags: c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae, visual-studio-2019

My code needs to test various pixel types for "validity".  For example, floating point pixels are invalid if they report `true` for `std::isnan()`.

So I have a "validator" template struct that I specialize for my various pixel types (here, just for `float`).   My code uses a global template function to invoke the right overload through SFINAE

```
// Dummy implementation breaks compilation if no overload found.
template<class PEL, typename Enable=void> struct pixel_validator  { };


template<class PEL> 
struct pixel_validator<PEL, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<PEL>::value>::type>
{
    static bool validate(const PEL& p) { return !std::isnan(p);  }
};


template<class PEL>
inline bool is_valid_pixel(const PEL& p) 
{
    // Dispatch to validator above
    return pixel_validator<PEL>::validate(p); 
};


void main
{
     float x = 1.0f;
     std::cout << "is it valid ?" << std::boolalpha << is_valid_pixel(x);
}
```

And this example works just fine.  The `pixel_validator` specialization for `float` is chosen. All is well.

But then I tried to reduce the verbosity of my template expressions for clarity via a custom version of "`std::enable_if`" specifically for `float`.

```
template<class T, class VAL=T>
struct enable_if_floating
    : std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, VAL>
{};
```

So now instead of writing this:

```
std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<PEL>::value>::type
```

I can write

```
enable_if_floating<PEL>::value
```

... so my validator becomes:

```
template<class PEL> 
struct pixel_validator<PEL, typename enable_if_floating<PEL>::type>
{
    static bool validate(const PEL& p) { return !std::isnan(p); }
};
```

Unfortunately, the moment that I change my "`pixel_validator`" to use it, the code fails to build.  My `enable_if_floating` does not work and so Visual Studio cannot find the appropriate specialization.  My output is not surprising then.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestApp7, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>TestApp7.cpp
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62,34): error C2039:  'validate': is not a member of 'pixel_validator<PEL,void>'
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62,34): error C2039:         with
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62,34): error C2039:         [
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62,34): error C2039:             PEL=float
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62,34): error C2039:         ]
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62): message :  see declaration of 'pixel_validator<PEL,void>'
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62): message :         with
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62): message :         [
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62): message :             PEL=float
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62): message :         ]
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(82): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'bool is_valid_pixel<float>(const PEL &)' being compiled
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(82): message :         with
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(82): message :         [
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(82): message :             PEL=float
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(82): message :         ]
1>C:\Test\TestApp7\TestApp7.cpp(62,1): error C3861:  'validate': identifier not found
1>Done building project "TestApp7.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

My question is, why?  What is wrong with my `enable_if_floating`?

Note: I even put this code in my `main()`, just for sanity checking.  If my template were bad, I would expect the `static_assert()` to fail, but it does not.

```
// Sanity check #2.  Does my enable_if_floating test  reports that float
// enables because it's numeric?  If not then the static_assert below should fail

using float_type = enable_if_floating<float>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<float_type, float>, "Not same as float...");
```

Note also:  My real world code uses a predicate that saves a whole lot more space than in this simple example

Comment: The second argument to std::enable_if in the definition of enable_if_floating is unnecessary, it seems

Comment: Well the idea was to use it just as the second argument is used in enable_if;  That is, sometimes I want  the type to which it evaluates (when it is chosen) to be different from the supplied type T

Comment: To be clear, I'm not posting this question to find a workaround, I'm posting it to understand why this approach does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure is the only problem but is a problem.

If you write

```
template<class T, class VAL=T>
struct enable_if_floating
    : std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, VAL>
{};
```

the default returned `type` is `T` where, for `std::is_enable_if`, is `void`.

So

```
template<class PEL> 
struct pixel_validator<PEL, typename enable_if_floating<PEL>::type>
{
    static bool validate(const PEL& p) { return !std::isnan(p); }
};
```

become, when `PEL` is a floating point type,

```
template<class PEL> // .....VVV   should be void, not PEL
struct pixel_validator<PEL, PEL>
{
    static bool validate(const PEL& p) { return !std::isnan(p); }
};
```

that doesn't matches the `pixel_validator` declaration (and main definition)

```
template<class PEL, typename Enable=void>
struct pixel_validator
 { };
```

because the expected second type is `void`, not `PEL`.

I see two possible alternative solutions: or you use `void` as default value for `enable_is_floating` second template parameter

```
// ...........................VVVV 
template<class T, class VAL = void>
struct enable_if_floating
    : std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, VAL>
 { };
```

or you use `PEL` as default value for `pixel_validator` second template parameter

```
template <typename PEL, typename = PEL>
struct pixel_validator
 { };
```

I suggest the first one to homogeneity with `std::enable_if` and standard C++ library.

Comment: According to the docs second argument to enable_if is just telling it the type to instantiate *if the bool is true*.  But if the bool is false, no type is instantiated and SFINAE should still work normally.  Shouldn't it?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/enable-if-class?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Joe - Exact. But when the main version of the struct expect (default value) a `void` as second template parameter, the specialization should have a `void` as second template parameter. If it is `PEL`, there isn't match so the main version is selected.

Comment: Oh good grief, of course!  (smacks head)   Now that you've pointed it out, I feel silly for not realizing it hours ago.    Even after 5 years of template meta-processing  my mind keeps slipping back into it's old-school C++ ways; I was treating this as if I were overloading functions rather than types

Thank you.